# i am executing one file called arrow-test.cc in apache-parquet(cpp), i am facing error: ‘MakeTable’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, parquet

```
arrow-test.cc:26:5: error: ‘MakeTable’ was not declared in this scope
   26 |     MakeTable(schema, {sip_array, dip_array}, &arrow_table);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "arrow/builder.h"
#include "arrow/table.h"
#include "arrow/io/file.h"
#include <parquet/arrow/writer.h>
#include <parquet/properties.h>

main() {
    arrow::Int32Builder sip_builder(arrow::default_memory_pool());
    arrow::Int32Builder dip_builder(arrow::default_memory_pool());
    for(size_t i=0; i < 1000; i++) {  // simulate row-oriented incoming data
        sip_builder.Append(i*100);
        dip_builder.Append(i*10 + i);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> sip_array;
    sip_builder.Finish(&sip_array);
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> dip_array;
    dip_builder.Finish(&dip_array);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>> schema_definition = {
        arrow::field("sip", arrow::int32(), false /* don't allow null; makes field required */),
        arrow::field("dip", arrow::int32(), false)
    };
    auto schema = std::make_shared<arrow::Schema>(schema_definition);
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> arrow_table;
    MakeTable(schema, {sip_array, dip_array}, &arrow_table);

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> file_output_stream;
    arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open("test.parquet", &file_output_stream);
    parquet::WriterProperties::Builder props_builder;
    props_builder.compression(parquet::Compression::GZIP);
    props_builder.compression("dip", parquet::Compression::SNAPPY);
    auto props = props_builder.build();
    parquet::arrow::WriteTable(*arrow_table, ::arrow::default_memory_pool(),
       file_output_stream, sip_array->length(), props);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: are you missing the namespace of the function? C++ is not a script language so it is not during execution.